# Bootstrap navbar isn't refreshing in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, react-bootstrap

My bootstrap navbar is working fine but when I click on current page navbar link, that link is unclickable means it is not letting me click on it again. Other navbar link are clickable except current narbar link.

```
<Navbar collapseOnSelect sticky='top' expand='sm' variant='dark' className='background color '>
    <Container >
      <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls='responsive-navbar-nav' />
      <Navbar.Collapse className='mobile-nav' id='responsive-navbar-nav'>
      <Nav className='me-auto'>
          <Nav.Link as={NavLink} to="/" >Home</Nav.Link>
      </Nav>
      <Nav>
          <Nav.Link as={NavLink} to="/about">About</Nav.Link>
          
       </Nav>
      </Navbar.Collapse>
    </Container>
  </Navbar>
```

Source code: https://codesandbox.io/s/eloquent-leaf-fjml2u?from-embed=&file=/src/Navigation/Navigation.js,

when I use `window.location.reload` I have to double click to refresh current page. First click will take to previous page and second click takes to current page

Comment: What does "current navbar link" mean? If you are trying to click a link to the path that is already being matched and rendered this is considered a non-op. Can you more clearly explain/describe the issue?

Comment: @DrewReese let's say home is displaying on the screen and if I try to click on the home page link from the home page then it is a unclickable link.  I think yes click a link to the path that isclick already matched and rendered. that's mean there isn't way to do it. Is there a alternative way?

Comment: @DrewReese I have navbar with fixed poistion on the top. If I scroll to half way and I click on link that should take me to top of the page or refresh/reload. I don't want to make unclickable link.

Comment: I see, so you are wanting some "scroll-to-top" behavior when a link it clicked? This isn't default behavior so you implement this yourself. Have you tried anything?

Comment: @DrewReese I tried window.scrollTo(0,0) and it is working fine. I am not sure, suppose if page is loading little long and I want to refresh/reload the page using the navbar link. window.scrollTo doesn't refresh the page, it only takes to top of the page. Any solution?

Comment: I tried <Nav.Link as={NavLink} to="/about" onClick={() => window.location.reload()}>About</Nav.Link> and useNavigate and useLocation. They aren't refreshing in a current way. I have to double click to refresh current page. First click will take to previous page and second click takes to current page

Comment: What is there to refresh? You still haven't included a [minimal, complete, and reproducible code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and clearly explained the issue. What are you trying to refresh? You very likely don't want to use `window.location.reload` and this just reloads the page and your entire app.

Comment: @DrewReese ok thanks. when I use `window.location.reload ` I have to double click to refresh current page. First click will take to previous page and second click takes to current page. Is there a way to put react router link in `window.location.reload(here) `.

Comment: Is it possible for you to create a *running* codesandbox demo of your code? It'll probably be a lot easier to help debug.

Comment: @DrewReese sure.I am going to do it right away

Comment: @DrewReese, I am importing from the github and it is taking long

Comment: @DrewReese, this is doing same thing [link](https://codesandbox.io/embed/eloquent-leaf-fjml2u?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark), while importing source taking quite long but I already built that does same thing

Answer (score 0):

> I have navbar with fixed position on the top. If I scroll to half way
> and I click on link that should take me to top of the page or
> refresh/reload.

You can create a hook to handle scrolling the window back to the top when the location changes.

Example:

```
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

const useScrollToTop = () => {
  const location = useLocation();
  React.useEffect(() => {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
  }, [location]);
};
```

If needed, create a component to handle using the `useScrollToTop` hook.

Example:

```
const ScrollToTop = () => {
  useScrollToTop();
  return null;
};
```

Usage:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <HashRouter>
      <ScrollToTop />
      <div className="App">
        <Navigation />
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
          <Route path="/about" element={<About />} />
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </HashRouter>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit bootstrap-navbar-isnt-refreshing-in-react]